# Repeat a sequence of dates (sheet attached)? Would like to convert to colums (GOOGLE SHEETS)

Tags: google-sheets, transpose

Cell E2: Transposed sequence, 366 days of data points starting from 1/31/22.

I have a model with 366 days of sales forecasts for 200 SKUs.

I would like this sequence to repeat in a column "X" number of times per the value in cell B3, so in this case, 200 times. How do I accomplish this?

Link to document is below:
[Transpose Sequence](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PJim63mQOLbuds9HIg9gCxZp4VVZqEK6QdH63p_m-Hw/edit#gid=0)

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question?

Comment: In cell E3, I have the sequence of dates. I need these sequence of dates to be vertical, and repeated 200 times. I am having issues with SPLIT and Transpose

Comment: @taylor.2317 - I added in the desired output format on the second tab

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SEQUENCE(Sheet1!B3)&"×"&
 SEQUENCE(1, Sheet1!B7, Sheet1!B8, Sheet1!B9)), "×"))
```

[image]

**[demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j6S6gnhHuWtMRVGlqG1fSM14LFLq9maT5BVbShTCzb4/edit#gid=1735518102)**